# Gatsby - Build website for stage/development - which command should I use?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How can I build/deploy a gatsby website for development environment?

If you run gatsby build the environment variable is **automatic set to production.**

**Use Case**: I do want to deploy my website to services such as Netlify, etc, but I want to BUILD for STAGE environment.  Anyone know which command I can use for that or if I should replace the NODE_ENV in the gatsby build command? I want to deploy and deliver the staging website to the **coworkers/users/customers,** then they will be able to **test** and use it on the **staging environment**. (with all staging configuration). If you are developing a website for customers you might need to deploy a staging version for test/validation purposes.

I know that gatsby/react internally have some different processing based on the environment, but I was wondering if it's possible to build and deploy a gatsby website for development/stage purposes using development variables configuration.

**An example:** I was using two plugins - gatsby-google-tag-manager and gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel and realized that both configurations relies on NODE_ENV development or production and I currently can not build and deploy a website using development environment.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: putting it to development would enable development warnings for customers, why would you want customers to go through that?

Comment: Hello @BoyWithSilverWings. Thanks for your answer. Not only customers but I also need to make my website available for coworkers or anyone else that is involved in using/testing the website. I also added on the answer that some plugins rely on NODE_ENV (production vs development) to work. 

If you are developing a website for any customer, you might need to deploy and make a test version available for test/validation purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#additional-environments-staging-test-etc

Answer (score 2):

`gatsby build` overrides `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

I solved it by using another environment variable to override `NODE_ENV` in `gatsby-config.js`

At the top of the file`gatsby-config.js`:

```js
if (process.env.DEVELOPMENT === 'TRUE') {
   process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
}

require ('dotenv'). config ({
   path: `.env. $ {process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

// etc...
```

Run development build:

`DEVELOPMENT=TRUE gatsby build`