# How can I use the production build of React with Gatsby in non-dev environment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

React toggles between the production and development builds by checking the `NODE_ENV`, however Gatsby forces this to `production` unless the site is running on the dev server (`gatsby start`). I need to debug some hydration issues that do not present when the site is build for the dev server, but I don't see any way to tell gatsby to use the `development` version of React when using [gatsby build](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/#build). It's possible to enable profiling but not a full development build.

[Edit] For clarity, `NODE_ENV=production gatsby build` does not work. Gatsby overrides `NODE_ENV`.

**How can I tell Gatsby to use the development build of react in a `gatsby build`**

Comment: Try using optional environment variables when running a gatsby build like this `NODE_ENV=development npm run build`

Comment: That doesn't work. Gatsby overrides this and forces this `production` as I mention in my question. I've made that clearer in the question.

Comment: I went looking for some other way of overriding the default gatsby behaviour and found some information on this StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69770395/11149234, does that one work for you?